# Flash message won't display in client side, how to solve?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, express-session, connect-flash

I have been following this [youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVQZAcb_CrE) and I'm trying to figure out how to work with `connect-flash` npm. This is the code I'm using:

**SERVER-SIDE:**

```
//app.js
const session = require('express-session');
const flash = require('connect-flash');

app.use(session({
  name: SESSION_NAME,
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  secret: SESSION_SECRET,
  cookie: {
      maxAge: SESSION_LIFETIME,
      sameSite: true,
      secure: IN_PROD
  }
}));
app.use(flash());

//users.js
//somewhere in USER LOGIN POST REQUEST:
if(!results.length) {
    console.log("    > Cannot fetch user from the database");
    req.flash('flash', 'some message in the alert');
    return res.redirect('/user_login');
}      

//USER LOGIN GET REQUEST:
router.get('/user_login', redirectHome, (req, res) => { 
    return res.render('userEntries/login', {message: req.flash('flash')});
});
```

**CLIENT-SIDE (EJS)**

```
<body>
    <% if(message.length > 0) { %>
        <div class="alert alert-success" style="text-align: center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
            <strong>INTRO: </strong>  <%= message %>
        </div>
    <% }%>
    ......
```

Now, the `post` and `get` request work fine in my application, but I just have no idea why flash messages won't work. These are the stuff I have tried:

- In EJS statement: I have also tried `if(message){...}`
- I tried saving flash message in `req.locals`
- I have tried using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T4Y3dj1nysk) - also didn't work.

Please note that sometimes the alerts will work, and sometimes the messages are passed multiple times! In the figure below, I've added an invalid username and password twice, waited for approx. five minutes and reloaded the page and this what happened:

[image: DEMO]

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. If you have any useful information please let me know. Thanks

Comment: What it shows when you print <% message %> without if ? i think it should be empty array or object, and when there is a error what it prints ? object or array ?

Comment: I have restarted my NODE server, and added `<p id="test9"><%= message %></p><script>console.log(document.getElementById("test9"));</script>` and it returns `<p id="test9">some message in the alert</p>` even if the request is not made!

Comment: Now that some time passed, and I have reloaded the page, it returns `<p id="test9"></p>` prior request and  `<p id="test9"></p>` when the request is made! When I refresh the page it will return: `<p id="test9">some message in the alert</p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are printing the errors like this

```
   <%= message %>
```

It won't work because message is an array.
You can display your errors like below

```
    <%= message[0] %>
```

OR
you can loop through your message array.

```
 for( m of message) {
         <%= m %>
 }
```

Comment: I will try it out and let you know if that worked ! Thanks for your reply @DharmikPatel

Comment: No problem. @LoizosVasileiou